# Plane Image that follows more than one camera?

Tags: camera, image, tracking

I'm creating a complex model of a city, there are a lot of trees.
I decided to go for cutout trees that follows the camera with a track constraint.
Now I need to create multiple points of view with cameras and I need the cutouts to face cameras when I switch from one to another camera.
I'm thinking to duplicate the cutouts for every points of view and change the constraint but it will too complicated. Maybe some composite node is able to do so?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be like this:

1a) Add an empty to your scene, add as many "object location constraints" as "copy location" as you have cameras, give each copy location constraint another camera as target

2b) add a "track to constraints" to all of your planes with target to your empty

In my example i have just two cams to explain how it works:

[image]

2. by animating the influence you can change the position of your empty like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked! I have just realized that actually I can add more track contraints actually. It was not clear to me from the interface and I didn't try. Actually I could add more track contraint to trees to follow different cameras and change the influence, but adding the empty makes things easier when I add a new camera. +1 for showing mehow influence works.

Comment: Glad it helped you